# finding odd numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays

I try to print the odd numbers in Java that are inside the array but this algorithm doesn't work ... May someone help me ? 
The printing result is that :

```
"Exception in thread "main" .java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at JavaArray.main(JavaArray.java:12)"
```

Code :

```
public class JavaArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = {1,3,4,5,8,9,10};

        int i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++); {

            if(myArray[i] % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            } 

        }       

    }

}
```

Comment: You can also just write `for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)` no need to declare `i` before the loop

Comment: dudes, myArray.length-1  !

Comment: int[] myArray = {1,3,4,5,8,9,10};
        for(int i : myArray)  {
            if(i % 2 == 1) 
                System.out.println(i);
        }

Answer (score 4):

Remove the semi-colon that is terminating your `for` loop

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++);
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have placed semicolon after for loop, variable i increments till length of array(here 7). After that loop ends and you are trying to access myarray element through i which is 7 so it is giving out of bound exception.

Comment: This is the only answer that explains the exception (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the extra ; you need to remove, you can consolidate by declaring the int in the loop declaration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      .
      .
      .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside @Reimus point , you can also do it like below  , sort the array if it's not sorted yet, in your case it is sorted . FYI, Instead of Collections.sort which is above O(N) complexity use a Hash Set.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] myArray={1,3,4,5,8,9,10};
Arrays.sort(str);
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] == str[i - 1]) {
    System.out.println("Dupe-num: " + str[i];
  }
}
}
```